# Latex (math mode) in Bokeh

Tags: python, latex, bokeh

all

Is there any chance I can use the math mode (latex code) in Bokeh? I checked all the Bokeh git issues (and possible options to solve) but nothing seems to work in my case :frowning:

Let’s say I have $\alpha_\beta$ (so alpha_beta) in my dataset (.csv) and I want to include it in a plot or hover - how would I do that? Sure I can use alpha symbol but how would I make beta be a subscript of alpha?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I got a response from Bryan on Bokeh Discourse. Unfortunately, no answer yet but the issue is being worked on https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/latex-math-mode-in-bokeh/7290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bokeh 2.4 adds support for LaTeX (and MathML) to some elements in Bokeh. Currently, you can use LaTeX on axis labels, tick labels, div widgets, and paragraph widgets. Unfortunately, LaTeX on hover labels is not yet supported, but LaTeX support for more elements should be added soon. For more information about the new math text feature and how to use them, see the [Bokeh 2.4 release blogpost](https://blog.bokeh.org/bokeh-2-4-6f8a842dfb4f), the new [blackbody radiation example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/latex_blackbody_radiation.html), and the [Bokeh user guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html#adding-mathematical-notations)!

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for following up here as well. I immediately shared the latex support update all over Twitter :) 

Kudos!